# Unhide UIButton with if statement

Tags: ios

I tried to unhide a UIButton in an if-statement, like so:

```
if(condition)
{
  myButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

but this did not work. Xcode says, "Property 'hidden' not found on object of type '_strong id'". I am not sure what that means.

Does anyone know how it is done?

Comment: It means you have myButton typed as id -- change it to UIButton* and it will work.

Comment: Or, `((UIbutton *)myButton).hidden = NO;`.

Comment: If you are sure myButton is kind of class `UIButton`, I believe just `[myButton setHidden:NO]` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(condition && [myButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
 {
      [((UIbutton *)myButton) setHidden:NO];
 }
```

Comment: You could do it this way, but it's really overkill. The button should be typed to UIButton* to start with, that's just good coding practice, so there shouldn't be any need to check its class or cast it.